# What is this insect from India called?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

[image]

It was found on a roof in Jaipur, Rajasthan, North-Western India.

Comment: Can you add some more details, like its size?

Answer (score 3):

It appears like a [pellucid hawkmoth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephonodes_hylas) (*Cephonodes hylas*; also called coffee bee hawkmoth). This belongs to the same family as the hummingbird hawk moths.

> [image]
>   From wikipedia

Many photographers have misidentified this one as the hummingbird hawkmoth (See the picture and the link below. So if you google `hummingbird moth india`, you'll get pictures of the pellucid hawkmoth too).

> [image]
>   Courtesy: [Nitin Prabhudesai](http://www.indianaturewatch.net/displayimage.php?id=373423)